# Check if is in top value django queryset

Tags: django

I have a django model

```
class City(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField()
    assets = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

How can I get the first three rows by user?

Comment: User.objects.all()[:3]

Answer (score 0):

To get the first 3 `City` objects ordered **ascending** by the `user` field, use:

```py
City.objects.all().order_by('user')[:3]
```

To get the first 3 `City` objects ordered **descending** by the `user` field use:

```py
City.objects.all().order_by('-user')[:3]
```

Notice the hyphen `-` before **user** in `order_by`

Answer (score 0):

First, create this serializer in file `serializers.py`

```
class CitySerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=City
        fields='__all__'
```

Now, write `views.py`

```
class CityView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset=City.objects.all()
        serializer=CitySerializer (queryset, many=True)
        return JsonResponse({"list":serializer.data})
```